# Application crash without error message - Help appreciated

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, crash

I am a little bit lost. My .Net application (Winforms) shows many user controls on a flowlayout panel. Sometimes when moving the screen around (controls have to be painted) or reloading the screen, the application exit without any messages. All I see are two entries in the eventviewer:

[image: eventviewer entries]

```
Anwendung: MainForm.exe
Frameworkversion: v4.0.30319
Beschreibung: Der Prozess wurde aufgrund einer unbehandelten Ausnahme beendet.
Ausnahmeinformationen: System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception
   bei System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.CreateHandle(System.Windows.Forms.CreateParams)
   bei System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateHandle()
   bei System.Windows.Forms.Control.get_Handle()
   bei System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateGraphicsInternal()
   bei System.Windows.Forms.ThreadExceptionDialog..ctor(System.Exception)
   bei System.Windows.Forms.Application+ThreadContext.OnThreadException(System.Exception)
   bei System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProcException(System.Exception)
   bei System.Windows.Forms.Control+ControlNativeWindow.OnThreadException(System.Exception)
   bei System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr)
   bei System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG ByRef)
   bei System.Windows.Forms.Application+ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr, Int32, Int32)
   bei System.Windows.Forms.Application+ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32, System.Windows.Forms.ApplicationContext)
   bei System.Windows.Forms.Application+ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32, System.Windows.Forms.ApplicationContext)
   bei System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(System.Windows.Forms.Form)
   bei MainForm.Program.Main()
```

```
Name der fehlerhaften Anwendung: MainForm.exe, Version: 1.22.8345.35922, Zeitstempel: 0x63680394
Name des fehlerhaften Moduls: KERNELBASE.dll, Version: 10.0.22000.1219, Zeitstempel: 0x554c45b0
Ausnahmecode: 0xe0434352
Fehleroffset: 0x00140762
ID des fehlerhaften Prozesses: 0x2a5c
Startzeit der fehlerhaften Anwendung: 0x01d8fa95dda003f6
Pfad der fehlerhaften Anwendung: C:\Users\MG\source\repos\SM1.22.8345.35933\MainForm\bin\Debug\MainForm.exe
Pfad des fehlerhaften Moduls: C:\Windows\System32\KERNELBASE.dll
Berichtskennung: a8a7b9a0-a5d1-4eb8-8340-39c6c236ad1a
Vollständiger Name des fehlerhaften Pakets: 
Anwendungs-ID, die relativ zum fehlerhaften Paket ist:
```

I am not a debugging pro and I hope that I might get a good tipp how the avoid these crashes. Any ideas are highly appreciated!

SUPPLEMENT:
Should I do something like this in the usercontrol?

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var threadParameters = new System.Threading.ThreadStart(delegate { WriteTextSafe("This text was set safely."); });
    var thread2 = new System.Threading.Thread(threadParameters);
    thread2.Start();
}
 
public void WriteTextSafe(string text)  
{  
    if (textBox1.InvokeRequired)  
    {  
        // Call this same method but append THREAD2 to the text  
        Action safeWrite = delegate { WriteTextSafe($"{text} (THREAD2)"); };  
        textBox1.Invoke(safeWrite);  
    }  
    else  
        textBox1.Text = text;  
}
```

Comment: Looks like a threading exception.  Maybe you are accessing a ui element from a separate thread without invoking it.

Comment: I have many instances of a user control placed on my MainForm. I do not explicitly use a new thread for this. I am changing properties in the usercontrol instances during runtime using public properties in the usercontrol. Are the usercontrol instances different threads?

Comment: Usercontrol instances will run on the main thread.  Do you have any BackgroundWorker instances?